# `scope` around `mount` ineffective?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, url-routing, blacklight

(While this discusses Blacklight engine, I believe the question is actually purely about Rails.)

I am trying to add internationalisation to my Blacklight app. To that end, I

- wrapped everything in `config/routes.rb` into `scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|ja/`, and
- in `app/controllers/application_controller.rb` I added `before_action :set_locale` and overrode `default_url_options`

as suggested by [Rails i18n guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html). Most things work, but there's one thing I haven't been able to figure out.

All of my application routes are correctly mapped, e.g. `http://www.example.com/en/catalog/12345` correctly matches with `(/:locale)/catalog/:id(.:format)`, and gets routed to `catalog#show` with `{:id=>/[^\/]+(?=\.json|\.html|$|\/)/, :locale=>/en|ja/}`). All of Devise's URLs are fine. Everything works... except the `mount`-ed Blacklight engine.

Apparently, the Blacklight engine doesn't listen to `scope`. `rake routes` shows:

```
Routes for Blacklight::Engine:
      search_history GET    /search_history(.:format)            search_history#index
      ....
```

and not `(:locale)/search_history(.:format)` as I would hope.

I have modified the Blacklight template so that I get a language chooser pointing to the current page in both Japanese and English, but when I navigate to `search_history`, `url_for` suddenly throws up when confronted with the `:locale` parameter.

Why does `mount` ignore `scope`? How do I solve my problem (engine routes also responding to `:locale`)?

Here's my default Blacklight-generated `config/routes.rb`, modified with `scope`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|ja/ do
    mount Blacklight::Engine => '/'
    root to: "catalog#index"
      concern :searchable, Blacklight::Routes::Searchable.new

    resource :catalog, only: [:index], as: 'catalog', path: '/catalog', controller: 'catalog', id: /[^\/]+(?=\.json|\.html|$|\/)/ do
      concerns :searchable
    end

    devise_for :users
    concern :exportable, Blacklight::Routes::Exportable.new

    resources :solr_documents, only: [:show], path: '/catalog', controller: 'catalog', id: /[^\/]+(?=\.json|\.html|$|\/)/ do
      concerns :exportable
    end

    resources :bookmarks, id: /[^\/]+(?=\.json|\.html|$|\/)/ do
      concerns :exportable

      collection do
        delete 'clear'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**tl;dr:** `scope` prefixes all of my routes, except the routes by `mount`. Why, and how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Rails is indeed ignoring `scope` in the engine routes, but I can add a scope for the engine explicitly:

```
Blacklight::Engine.routes.default_scope = { path: "(:locale)", locale: /en|ja/ }
mount Blacklight::Engine => '/'
```

However, that still does not solve my issues (continued in [`link_to` with parameters for an Engine route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965303/link-to-with-parameters-for-an-engine-route)).