# `link_to` with parameters for an Engine route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-routing, rails-engines, blacklight

(While this discusses Blacklight engine, I believe the question is actually purely about Rails.)

Continuing my quest from [`scope` around `mount` ineffective?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44944848/scope-around-mount-ineffective) (tl;dr: make the engine routes obey the same `:locale` scope as application routes), after digging through Rails source.

Currently, I have this setup:

```
# config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do      
  Blacklight::Engine.routes.default_scope = { path: "(:locale)", locale: /en|ja/ }
  mount Blacklight::Engine => '/'

  scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|ja/ do
    # ...
  end
end
```

This makes the routes work properly. However, I had this view code to generate the alternate-language links to the current page (guided by [link_to the current page plus/merged with a param [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535908/link-to-the-current-page-plus-merged-with-a-param/5535972)):

```
<div id="languages_nav_popup" class="navbar-inverse">                                                                                                                                                          
  <% locales.each do |locale| %>
    <% next if locale == I18n.locale %>
    <%= link_to params.permit!.merge(locale: locale) do %>                                             
      <img src="<%= url_for "/img/flag/#{locale}.png" %>"/>                                            
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

That `link_to` fails when the current page is an Engine route. This is due to this piece of code in `actionpack`:

```
# lib/action_dispatch/journey/formatter.rb
# Skip this route unless a name has been provided or it is a
# standard Rails route since we can't determine whether an options
# hash passed to url_for matches a Rack application or a redirect.
next unless name || route.dispatcher?
```

With `link_to options, &block` syntax that I use above, `name` is `nil`; and `dispatcher?` is `false` for an engine route. (If I pass that check by inserting a name by force, I get a nonsensical URL like `.../assets?action=index&controller=saved_searches&locale=ja`).

I'm getting desperate here, almost to the point where I'm thinking the best way to deal with this is regexp. This atrocity works:

```
<%= link_to request.base_url + request.original_fullpath.sub(%r{(?<=/)#{I18n.locale}}, locale.to_s) do %
```

Is there no way to generate the correct URL properly?

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution to this? Did you ever see this issue (and PR fixing it): https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/33219
Not sure that the behavior is the same if you embed an engine inside of a `scope {}` though.

Comment: @Andrei I did not... I've moved on though, and this question is not relevant for me any more, so I did not see it.

Answer (score 0):

Another totally hacky solution is to copy the engine routes to your local routes.rb and add a warning that triggers on gem update to check them for changes. :(